# Нет репозиториев в Qt Maintenance Tool

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Решил установить плагин который я в начале не установил, устанавливаю `Qt 5.12` не сетевым установщиком.

Ошибка: `` Нет репозиториев в Qt Maintenance Tool (`MaintenanceTool.exe`). ``

Где их найти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне подошёл вот этот адрес:

http://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/root/qt/

для линукса тут

http://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/root/qt/

[нашёл тут](https://forum.qt.io/topic/31796/no-default-repositories-in-maintenance-tool/12)